# Blender 2.8 can't find my intel gpu

Tags: gpu

I was following a tutorial on YouTube when I realized that in render mode GPU is clickable but does not work. I tried doing what i saw online but couldn't find my GPU in the system preference. The information about my PC is: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-5005U CPU @ 2.00GHZ. And the GPU i'm using is Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 driver with OpenCl 2.0 and OpenGl 4.4.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately your integrated graphics card doesn't fulfill the requirements [for GPU rendering in Blender 2.8x](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#supported-hardware). You would either need a

- Nvidia graphics card with CUDA compute capability 3.0 or higher
- AMD graphics card from GCN second generation or later

> **CUDA**
>
> CUDA requires graphics cards with compute capability 3.0 and higher. To make sure your GPU is supported, see the [list of Nvidia graphics cards](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) with the compute capabilities and supported graphics cards. CUDA GPU rendering is supported on Windows, macOS, and Linux.

---

> **AMD**
>
> OpenCL is supported for GPU rendering with AMD graphics cards. Blender supports graphics cards with GCN generation 2 and above. To make sure your GPU is supported, see the [list of GCN generations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Core_Next#Iterations) with the GCN generation and supported graphics cards.
>
> AMD OpenCL GPU rendering is supported on Windows and Linux, but not on macOS.

Comment: But the official website redirected me to this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_graphics_processing_units saying it works

Comment: @UnSpecificCoding I assume you're referring to the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) page? The *Supported Graphics Cards* section is for the required GPU for *running* Blender 2.8x. As noted below on the same page, *GPU rendering* has higher requirements. "These requirements are for basic Blender operation, rendering using the graphics card requires slightly different requirements."

Comment: @RobertGützkow no, he means the developer blog: https://code.blender.org/2019/04/supported-gpus-in-blender-2-80/.

Comment: @EricXue The answer is still the same though. Those are the minimum requirements for the GPUs in order to run Blender. GPU rendering has higher minimum requirements.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answer, this will not work, for the mentioned reasons. But even if it was to work, you have to remember that the GPUs that are built into CPU are generally very weak. You have an i3, so even weaker. I have an i5 and i7 and these GPUs built in are useless for the heavy lifting that is rendering on Blender or any other 3D App.

And: Even if you could make it work, it would be super slow.

Intel integrated graphics are fine for running a desktop, but not for heavy 3D work or number crunching like done with Blender with OpenCL and CUDA on AMD GPUs and Nvidia.

You are better off using the CPU itself, instead of its tiny little GPU addon.
But remember that 3D rendering work is probably one of the most demanding work you can throw at a computer.
I have scenes that I render that take 10 hours to finish, just one frame, on relatively powerful hardware.