# Confused about requirements for rendering

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

This is probably a small matter, but I'm new here and everything is still confusing. I have a Dell i5-3570 and nothing fancy for graphics yet. When I run a program called "GPU caps" it says that my setup has OpenCL level 1.2. But when I go to "Blender Preferences - System" if I ask to use OpenCL for rendering it says I don't have an OpenCL-compatible card and have to use CPU-only. (I tried to upgrade the driver, Intel said they have a new one but they won't install it because the manufacturer hasn't approved it, and I contacted the manufacturer and they said they won't bother evaluating the new driver because the system is too old, even though it's a quad running at 3.4 GHz.) It seems like the program ought to be able to correctly assess the hardware environment, what's my incentive to upgrade the GPU if it might not correctly recognize the new one either? Or is there just a minimum level of OpenCL the program has to see to say it's "compatible"? Thanks.

Comment: do you have an NVidia 920MX?

Comment: I wish. All I have is the "Intel 2500", thinking maybe a GTX 1050 Ti LP later when my stimulus comes in. It still ought to correctly recognize what I have though. Maybe it's the analysis tool that's wrong, like I say I don't know much about this stuff. (The manufacturer said the initial version of the setup was OpenCL 1.1 but that document was referencing an earlier version of the CPU so I think the 1.2 is the right number.) Hey I'm trying to do the bits of homework I can understand!

Comment: Your hardware doesn't fulfill the [requirements for GPU rendering](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#supported-hardware).

Comment: Related question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/173480

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% sure on this but you can try CUDA and check only your GPU (or both if you want). As far as I know, blender requires GCN generation 2 and up. Im not sure if that is the number you're referencing, but I would try CUDA first.

Comment: Thank you. It would have made more sense if the requirement (and also the selection tab) option was something relevant like "GCN 2+" rather than something like "OpenCL" which is essentially irrelevant as regards what has to be present. I guess we're a long way from the days when if you met the requirements for an "industry standard requirement" you could expect the thing you plugged in to actually work. And I had just learned that it was now OpenCL not OpenGL! By the time I'm ready to need this info it'll probably all go over to fiber optics not wires. Sorry to upset you, it's not your fault!

Comment: Not really, OpenCL is a framework, like Cuda & Optix. Choosing Either of these in Blender means to choose which framework Blender should use, which is possible only if you have the appropriate GPU. GCN is only a bunch of architecture instructions used by AMD GPUs for basic functioning. See it like frameworks being recipes and GCN an ingredient. Each recipe uses different ingredients that are specific, but give a similar end result. If you don't have the right ingredients, you can't use a recipe. Yet it doesn't make sense to name the recipe by all its required ingredients.